# Product of convex functions with special properties

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, functions, convex-analysis

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be non-negative, convex functions in $C^2([M,\infty))$, where  $M > 0$. Also, assume $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $[M,\infty)$, and that $g(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[M,\infty)$. We also have that $g(M) \geq f(M)$, and that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)g(x) = 0$.

Does this imply that $f(x)g(x)$ is decreasing on the whole domain $[M,\infty)$?

Help much appreciated!

Edit: Added that $g(M) \geq f(M)$, and hence $g(x) > f(x)$ for all $x \in (M,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an example where $g(M) = 0$.

EDIT: For the revised question:
$$ M = 1,\; f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, \; g(x) = \cases{x^3 & for $1 \le x \le 2$\cr 12 x - 16 & for $x \ge 2$} $$

Comment: thanks! this case can be excluded though, see the edited question.

Comment: It did provide an answer before the question was changed.

Comment: ... and now it does again.

Comment: @Robert Israel $g$ is not a  $C^{2}$ function.

Comment: True.  A small adjustment will correct that.

Comment: nice, thank you again. do you think it will hold if $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing and $g'(x)$ is strictly increasing, to?

Comment: $f'$ in the example is strictly increasing.  A slight modification to $g$ will make $g'$ strictly increasing too.